# Login with Facebook error code 190 in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, react-native, facebook-login

I am trying to handle the response after the user is logged through FB and I receive correctly the response as object. When I try to save it setting a state 'userInfo' and I try to console log the state I get an error 190. Any thought? Here is my code

Request:

```html
  async loginWithFacebook() {

    const {type, token} = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync
    ('mytoken 32832839etc', {permissions: ['public_profile']})

      if (type == 'success') {
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token)
        const response = await fetch(
          'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id.name.picture.type(large)');
          const userInfo = await response.json();
          this.setState({ userInfo });
          console.log(this.state.userInfo);
          Alert.alert(
            'Logged In'
          );

        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch((error) =>{
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
      return 
  }
```

and this is the error message

Object {
   "error": Object {
   "code": 190,
   "fbtrace_id": "ERl8VWIrluv",
   "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
 },
}